# Splitting up Azure Functions without creating new function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Our existing system uses App Services with API controllers.

This is not a good setup because our scaling support is poor, its basically all or nothing

I am looking at changing over to use Azure Functions

So effectively each method in a controller would become a new function

Lets say that we have a taxi booking system

So we have the following

**Taxis**
GetTaxis
GetTaxiDrivers

**Drivers**
GetDrivers
GetDriversAvailableNow

In the app service approach we would simply have a TaxiController and DriverController with the the methods as routes

How can I achieve the same thing with Azure Functions?

Ideally, I would have 2 function apps - Taxis and Drivers with functions inside for each

The problem with that approach is that 2 function apps means 2 config settings, and if that is expanded throughout the system its far too big a change to make right now

Some of our routes are already quite long so I cant really add the "controller" name to my function name because I will exceed the 32 character limit

Has anyone had similar issues migrating from App Services to Azure Functions>

Paul

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with that approach is that 2 function apps means 2 config
> settings, and if that is expanded throughout the system its far too
> big a change to make right now

This is why application setting is part of the release process. You should compile once, deploy as many times you want and to different environments using the same binaries from the compiling process. If you're not there yet, I strongly recommend you start by automating the CI/CD pipeline.

Now answering your question, the proper way (IMHO) is to decouple taxis and drivers. When requested a taxi, your controller should add a message to a Queue, which will have an Azure Function listening to it, and it get triggered automatically to dequeue / process what needs to be processed.

Advantages:

- Your controller response time will get faster as it will pass the processing to another process
- The more messages in the queue / more instances of the function to consume, so it will scale only when needed.
- Http Requests (from one controller to another) is not reliable (unless you implement properly a circuit breaker and a retry policy. With the proposed architecture, if something goes wrong, the message will remain in the queue or it won't get completed by the Azure function and will return to the queue.

Comment: Thanks for this I was using taxi and drivers as an example my system is far more complex and the front end has a single url to call for the back end Api followed by the route. Implementing a function to replace each controller which is the original way I thought of is a huge change because if I have 20 controllers that’s 20 urls the front end needs to know about

Comment: Ah hang on do you mean to keep the api in place but just rip the code out to put a message onto service bus that a function picks up? That won’t work for calls that expect a response

Comment: but believe me, that's the right way. You should return an endpoint to check the status of the processing. Take a look, maybe you could add Durable Functions too, which offer this for you. PS: your front end will just do another call to keep checking the status. Backend will be basically API and processing moving to Azure Functions triggered by Queue messages

Comment: I agree this is the correct way to go however, I am just not sure about the amount of work required to change all of our calls to the backend which current call a known URL followed by a route.  In this method we would have to store https://ourcompany.taxis.microsoft.net/ and https://ourcompany.drivers.microsoft.net/, etc.  In my system that potentially means creating 50 function apps (which is fine) then changing the front end to know about the correct url to call out of the 50 (ignoring the route), thats not fine.  Also, the existing routes plus the URL for the function itself may exceed 32